# How to echo the current git branch in my Travis Build

Tags: git, travis-ci, git-branch

I am unable to get branch in travis build.
If I do echo $(git branch) in the script and run it in Travis.
It echoes ***(HEAD detached at 82abe25) master***

Is there anyway, I can just get the branch name?
I emphasize it is in Travis.

I also tried git symbolic-ref --short HEAD but in vain.

Comment: The branch should be passed to the build task and stored in some variable. Read that variable instead.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you?
Isin't there any way I can get the branch from Travis

Comment: This may help, https://unhashable.com/getting-the-current-branch-name-during-a-pull-request-in-travis-ci/

Comment: Actually not. So we have to write a script and have to make is as generic as possible as the same script can be used in Jenkins pipeline.
So, I can't use any Travis variable.

Comment: As it's always a detached HEAD, `git branch` and `git symbolic-ref` can't work. Which event triggers the build?

Comment: Push and pull both trigger the build

Comment: For a known commit, we can use `git for-each-ref --contains $commit` in a updated mirror clone to list all possible refs that contain the commit. But I'm not sure which ref is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the name of the branch being built by reading the `TRAVIS_BRANCH` environment variable.

From the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables):

> `TRAVIS_BRANCH:`
>
> - for push builds, or builds not triggered by a pull request, this is the name of the branch.
> - for builds triggered by a pull request this is the name of the branch targeted by the pull request.
> - for builds triggered by a tag, this is the same as the name of the tag (`TRAVIS_TAG`).

---

Reading [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460387/how-to-echo-the-current-git-branch-in-my-travis-build/63463695#comment112217848_63460387), I understand you want to run the same script [in Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables), as well. Most CI servers will check out a specific commit when running a build (i.e. a *detached HEAD*), so you won't be able to use Git to determine which branch you're on.

You're better off just checking for different environment variables in your script:

```sh
if [[ -v $TRAVIS_BRANCH ]]; then
    branch=$TRAVIS_BRANCH
elif [[ -v $GIT_BRANCH ]]; then
    branch=$GIT_BRANCH
fi
```